# React Native Scrollview detect negative scroll

Tags: react-native

I am using a code snippet like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.state.scrollY.addListener((value) => this.handleScroll(value));
  }

  handleScroll(pullDownDistance) {
//pull down distance knows how much you pulled

}
```

To detect when a user is attempting to scroll. the 'pullDownDistance' variable will give you the distance of each pull down.

I am trying to emulate something like the gif implemented below:

Something like this gif: https://github.com/LennyBoyatzis/RN-Pull-To-Refresh-Gears/blob/master/images/giphy.gif

Where it is possible to pull the scroll view in the opposite direction, and then it will reload. I can't seem to get the view to detect any sort of 'pull down in the opposite direction, as the pulldown function (handleScroll) does not seem to be executed.

is there a way to detect scrolls in that direction?

Comment: you want to see the view when you pull down?

Comment: @Codesingh yeah basically, It seems like iOS behaives different than android (that gif is iOS), but I am just trying to figure out how I can detect when the user is 'pulling down' the view basically

Comment: android is behaving better than ios?

Comment: are you using any third party ?

Comment: *Where it is possible to pull the scroll view in the opposite direction *, do you mind throwing some light on  what do you mean by this ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing here. Is `this.state.scrollY` a `ScrollView`? Because that's not what state is for. `ScrollView` has a `onScroll` property you can use to point to your handler. Also, check the `RefreshControl` component.

Answer (score 3):

If you implement onScroll handler of a ScrollView (RN 0.57), you'll notice that when you overscroll (meaning: scroll up, while scrollview is already at top), the event `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y` has negative values for iOS, but it remains 0 for Android.

Therefor, for iOS it's quite easy to detect negative scroll. For Android you'll have to look for some other solution.